# IE8 not saving cookie values?

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8, setcookie

I'm having some problems with IE8 respecting a cookie I'm setting via the jQuery cookie plugin.  Things are working fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE6 and IE7 (via IETester), but IE8 just doesn't seem to be storing the cookie.

If I F12 to the dev toolbar and check the cookies from the "Cache" menu item, I can see my cookie after I set it.  I also see other cookies being set but I only have my test page as my home page.  I have a bunch of cookies for microsoft and coolwebdeveloper.com (I pulled that site up and don't remember ever going there)???

Below is the cookie I'm setting/verifying through the dev toolbar.

```
NAME  filters 
VALUE  show 
DOMAIN  mydomain.com
PATH  /my/neat/path/ 
EXPIRES  3/12/2011 6:30:02 PM
```

When I quit/relaunch IE8, that cookie doesn't persist (it's set to expire 31 days out).

Anyone have any ideas?  Is there some preference setting I can check? Could this be some IT setting/firewall thing I can't do anything about?

I did try options -> privacy -->lower the internet zone to "accept all cookies" but that didn't make a difference.  I do have a little highlighted note at the bottom of the screen "some settings are managed by your system administrator", though.

Also, in View -> Webpage Privacy Policy, the domain I'm testing under says "no cookies were restricted or blocked".

Answer (score 0):

In internet Options under browsing history uncheck the "Delete browsing history on exit", which is checked by default.  This not only deletes the history but also deletes cookies.